# How to build GDAL 1.8 from source on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, build-process, geospatial, gdal

Does anyone know or have instructions on how to build GDAL 1.8 (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource) from source on Windows XP? I can't find any Windows executable for this version (still only available for 1.6.3). Note that I am NOT looking for a bloated version accompanied by other software.

EDIT: I tried the outdated instructions given in some of the links below, and they are not at all useful. Can someone who has had success with this give clear steps (version 1.8 is now available, so steps on building that version would be even better)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to compile from source when you have good pre-built versions AND good instructions...

The best (working) instructions I have found so far are [here](https://pythongisandstuff.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/installing-gdal-and-ogr-for-python-on-windows/). The downloads are from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714165130/http://www.gisinternals.com:80/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-8-mapserver-6-0.zip) (click on the download link to get a full list of files and to be able to download individual files). The two files I used were [GDAL-1.8.1.win32-py2.6.exe](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-8-mapserver-6-0%5CGDAL-1.8.1.win32-py2.6.exe) (python bindings) and [gdal-18-1600-core.msi](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-8-mapserver-6-0%5Cgdal-18-1600-core.msi) (core gdal utilities). Don't forget to add the environment variables to your PATH and to GDAL_DATA.

Answer (score 0):

There are nightly builds available here that can be downloaded and configured to work much like FWTools:

EDIT:

Current URL is this one: [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php)

This is the old one: http://vbkto.dyndns.org/sdk/

Comment: Dead link, unfortunately...  :(

Comment: it's not always dead, now for instance

Answer (score -1):

There are instructions on the trac wiki:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildHints

Comment: These don't work. Were you really able to build from source using these instructions (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnWindows)?

Comment: following instructions can be difficult, use the nightly builds

Comment: Can't connect from work, the firewall must have an issue with the dyndns address :(